# how to get twitter top tweets in specific language?

Tags: php, twitter, tweets, tweetstream

With this url you can get the 100 best recent tweets which have the word 'ALI':

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=ALI&result_type=popular&count=100&lang=en
```

But how can we keep `q` empty ?

I just want to get the top tweets by language and not by keyword.

I tried to put space for the `q` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a term like "lang:et" or "lang:ja".  Most of the features are part of the "q" param instead of additional params.

You can generally experiment with search by going to [Advanced Search](https://twitter.com/search-advanced?lang=en-gb) and after you search copy the query out of the search bar at the top right of the page.

e.g. 1 Japanese tweets, using q=lang%3Aja

```
$ twitterapi '/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=lang%3Aja&result_type=popular&count=1' | jq .statuses[].text
"ぽい！ま〜きの"
```